# Measure that couns occurences and groups in bins

Tags: powerbi, histogram, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

I am trying to create a measure that counts the occurences of all distinct values in a column and groups them into bins that I defined in a disconnected table. Subsequently a histogram (bar-chart) should be created.
A simplified example would look like this:

| SalesP |
| --- |
| John |
| Peter |
| Peter |
| Robert |
| John |
| John |

This should lead to the following result:

| SalesP | Count |
| --- | --- |
| John | 3 |
| Peter | 2 |
| Robert | 1 |

The bin range is defined in a disconnected table:

| From-To | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0-1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2-3 | 2 | 3 |
| 4-5 | 4 | 5 |

The final output in Excel should then give me

| From-To | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 0-1 | 1 |
| 2-3 | 2 |
| 4-5 | 0 |

I have created a similar measure where I grouped by revenues, but I cant get my head around the problem above.

```
IF(HASONEVALUE(Container[MinValRange]);COUNTROWS(FILTER(VIB; VIB[AM_VOL]>=VALUES(Container[MinValRange])&&VIB[AM_VOL]<VALUES(Container[MaxValRange])));COUNTROWS(VIB))
```

Any hints for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two measures for this

```
Measure = COUNTROWS(_sales)

Measure2 =
COUNTX (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        DISTINCT ( ADDCOLUMNS ( _sales, "count", [Measure] ) ),
        "test",
            MAXX (
                FILTER ( _bin, [From] <= EARLIER ( [count] ) && [To] >= EARLIER ( [count] ) ),
                [From-To]
            )
    ),
    [test]
)
```

[image: Solution]